# Counting references in a self referenced table based on both the referring and referenced rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a table that stores two levels of tasks (let's call it `primary` and `secondary`), in the same table using self-referential foreign keys. Column `secondary_for` is a self-reference on `tasks.id` where as `user` is a reference to a different table.

Each `primary` task will need 2 `secondary` tasks to be sourced from various users (one from each) other than the user who created the `primary` task for it to be "resolved". Given a user, I'm trying to find a way to rank the unresolved `primary` tasks for that user (so I can create a new `secondary` task against it) that enables the fastest completion of addressing the unresolved `primary` tasks.

So, if the state of `tasks` table is as follows:

```
+----+------+---------------+-----------------------------+
| id | user | secondary_for |            desc             |
+----+------+---------------+-----------------------------+
|  1 |    1 | NULL          | Primary Task 1              |
|  2 |    2 | 1             | Update 1 for Primary Task 1 |
|  3 |    3 | 1             | Update 2 for Primary Task 1 |
|  4 |    2 | NULL          | Primary Task 2              |
|  5 |    1 | 4             | Update 1 for Primary Task 2 |
|  6 |    3 | NULL          | Primary Task 3              |
+----+------+---------------+-----------------------------+
```

... and user 100 (who exists in `users` table), is available to add a secondary task, I want to present a list of eligible primary row ids sorted by the number of the secondary task against it currently:

```
+-----------+
| id |  ctr |
+-----------+
|  4 |    1 |
|  6 |    0 |
+-----------+
```

Here rows 4 and 6 are presented because:

1. they are primary tasks which user 100 hasn't created
2. user 100 hasn't already created a secondary task against these tasks
3. they don't have the required number of secondary tasks (ie. 2) yet,
   as opposed to row 1

I'm new to MySQL so I'm not sure how to approach this, but here's what I've got so far:

```
SELECT secondary_for AS id, COUNT(id) AS ctr FROM tasks
WHERE secondary_for IN
    (SELECT id FROM tasks WHERE secondary_for IS NULL AND user !=100)
    AND user != 100
GROUP BY secondary_for
HAVING COUNT(id) < 2
ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC
```

which gets me upto:

```
+-----------+
| id |  ctr |
+-----------+
|  4 |    1 |
+-----------+
```

but does not show row 6, which is also eligible but is not retrieved as there are no secondary tasks assigned to it yet.

How can I fix this? Also, I am almost certain that there is a more efficient way to construct this query using JOINs but don't know how to go about it.

Any help would be highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: in your sample there is not user 100..

Comment: @scaisEdge user is a foreign key to a users table (not shown here). I assumed that wouldn't affect the answer. updated the question to clarify.

Comment: Still no 100 here

Comment: there is no 6 in id column because in the select condition you're starting from secondary_for_id...what is it? If it is secondary_for the problem is that 6 is not present in this column.

Comment: @Gufus Yes, exactly- since there are no secondary tasks for row 6, I want it to appear in the results with ctr=0. I understand my current query will not help with this. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
SELECT A.id, ISNULL(B.ctr,0) AS ctr
FROM tasks A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT secondary_for, COUNT(*) AS ctr
           FROM tasks
           WHERE user!=100
           GROUP BY secondary_for) B
ON A.id=B.secondary_for
WHERE A.secondary_for IS NULL
AND A.user != 100
AND ISNULL(B.ctr,0)<2
ORDER BY ISNULL(B.ctr,0) DESC
```